# Git Checkout from different branches in jenkins

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am trying to take the chekouts from a different branches,

```
stage ("git-checkout"){
   steps  {
   checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
   branches: [[name: '**']],
  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
  extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Gitlb_creds', url: 'https://gitlab.com']]])
          }
```

I have passed a string parameter as branch in the job configuration where I have multiple branches in git lab repo but it is taking checkouts from only one single branch even after the changing the value.
But I want to trigger the pipeline as per my choice branch either from dev, master or any feature from the git lab repo.
Is there a possible way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the your `BRANCH` parameter to fill in during checkout, you have to specify like this:

```
    stage ("git-checkout"){
      steps  {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
             branches: [[name: ${BRANCH}]],
             doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
             extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [],
             userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Gitlb_creds', url: 'https://gitlab.com']]])
          }
```